# Using polymer ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer

I have the following polymer element which I have created:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">

<dom-module id="task-list-app">
    <style>
        :host {

        }
    </style>
    <template>
        <iron-ajax auto url="../tasks.json" handle-as="json" on-response="handleResponse"></iron-ajax>
        <template is="dom-repeater" items="{{todos}}">
            <span>hello</span>
        </template>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "task-list-app",
        created: function () {
            this.todos = [];
        },

        handleResponse: function (data) {
            this.todos = data.detail.response;
        }
    });
</script>
```

I am calling this inside my index.html by doing:

```
<task-list-app></task-list-app>
```

I am expecting that for every object returned in the todo array, a `<span>` will be printed. However, when I run the app, I get the following output in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'todos' of undefined

in `polymer.html line 1001`

I am not sure what is happening here and how to reference the data received back from the ajax response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After banging my head on the wall for a few hours I have managed to solve this. I have created my own element called `ajax-service` that has a public property called `todos` which is an `Array`. In this element, I use the `iron-ajax` element to do the ajax call.

When the ajax is complete, a function is called and the response is set on the `todos` property. I have also set the keys `reflectToAttribute` and `notify` to true. This means the `todos` property's value is reflected back to the attribute on the host node and that it is available for two-way binding (see [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html) for more information).

My `task-list-app` element is as follows:

```
<link rel="import" href="ajax-service.html">
<link rel="import" href="task-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="tiny-badge.html">

<dom-module id="task-list-app">
    <style>
        :host {

        }
    </style>
    <template>
        <ajax-service todos="{{todos}}"></ajax-service>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{todos}}">
            <task-item task="{{item}}"></task-item>
        </template>
        <div>
            <tiny-badge>[[todos.length]]</tiny-badge> total tasks
        </div>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "task-list-app"
    });
</script>
```

and my `ajax-service` element:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">

<dom-module id="ajax-service">
    <style>
        :host {

        }
    </style>
    <template>
        <iron-ajax auto url="../tasks.json" handle-as="json" on-response="tasksLoaded"></iron-ajax>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "ajax-service",
        properties: {
            todos: {
                type: Array,
                reflectToAttribute: true,
                notify: true
            }
        },
        attached: function () {
            this.todos = [];
        },
        tasksLoaded: function (data) {
            this.todos = data.detail.response;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Doing it this way means I am able to edit the data in the `on-response` function before setting it on the element.

Comment: You really don't want `reflectToAttribute: true`, especially for Array or Object data. It spams your DOM with potentially massive JSON, and is not needed for binding.

Answer (score 12):

First of all second template that you are using to loop through your data should be a "**dom-repeat**" and not a "**dom-repeater**". Secondly you can directly bind the response of iron-ajax to your looping template. Like this,

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">

<dom-module id="task-list-app">
    <style>
        :host {

        }
    </style>
    <template>
        <iron-ajax auto url="../tasks.json" handle-as="json" last-response="{{ajaxResponse}}"></iron-ajax>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ajaxResponse.todos]]">
            <span>{{item.todoItem}}</span>
        </template>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "task-list-app"
    });
</script>
```

So you are basically binding value of **last-response** property to your looping template directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've managed to get it working now. Let's say I needed to modify the response data first, how could I get this to work using the handleResponse call back?

Comment: Also, if I wanted to push a new Object into that array, how would I do that?

Answer (score 5):

You need to define property before using it in scripts:

```
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: "task-list-app",
    properties: {
      todos: {
        type: Array,
        notify: true
      }
    },

    handleResponse: function (data) {
      this.todos = data.detail.response;
    }
  });
</script>
```