# Polymer 1.0 services issue

Tags: polymer, web-component

I'm working on a reddit client using polymer to check out web compoments technologies. I started with the 0.5 version and got back on this project recently. That when I found out that polymer had the 1.0 released so I started over (as it wasn't that advanced anyway).

I have a service that use the iron-ajax to request reddit api and look for the posts. Here is the code :

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">

<dom-module id="reddit-list-service">
    <template>
        <iron-ajax
            url='https://www.reddit.com/new.json'
            handle-as='json'
            debounce-duration="300"
            on-response='handleResponse'
            debounce-duration="300"
            auto>

        </iron-ajax>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
    (function () {
        Polymer({
            is: 'reddit-list-service',
            properties: {
                modhash: {
                    type: String,
                    value: function() {
                        return '';
                    }
                },
                posts: {
                    type: Array,
                    value: function () {
                        return [];
                    }
                },
                after: {
                    type: String,
                    value: function () {
                        return '';
                    }
                }
            },

            // Update object properties from the ajax call response
            handleResponse: function (resp) {
                this.properties.modash = resp.detail.response.data.modhash;
                this.properties.posts = resp.detail.response.data.children;
                this.properties.after = resp.detail.response.data.after;
                this.post = this.properties.posts; // just to try
                console.log(this.properties.posts);
            }
        });
    })();
</script>
```

My log shows me that I get posts from the API and that's great!

Here's the issue when I want to use this service to make a list out of the posts array I can't figure out how to get them into my list compoment which is below :

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../reddit-list-service/reddit-list-service.html">

<dom-module id="reddit-post-list">
    <template>
        <reddit-list-service posts="{{posts}}">
        </reddit-list-service>

        <template is="dom-repeat" id="post-list" posts="{{posts}}">
            <p>{{post.author}}</p>
        <template>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
    (function () {
        Polymer({
            is: 'reddit-post-list',
            properties: {
            },
        });
    })();
</script>
```

I've tried several think I saw in the documentation but I can't figure out what's wrong the author property doesn't show up.

Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few things that aren't quite right here. In `reddit-post-list` you are not using the `dom-repeat` template correctly. See below:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="reddit-list-service.html">

<dom-module id="reddit-post-list">
    <template>
        <reddit-list-service posts="{{posts}}"></reddit-list-service>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[posts]]">
             <p>{{item.data.author}}</p>
        </template>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "reddit-post-list"
    });
</script>
```

You need an attribute called `items` which is the array the `dom-repeat` will iterate over. Inside the iteration you need to refer to `item` as this is the array item for the current iteration. [Here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-repeat) are the docs.

For you `reddit-list-service`, you need to set the the `reflectToAttribute` and `notify` attributes to `true` on your `posts` property. This means that any changes to this property are reflected back on the `posts` attribute on the `reddit-list-service` element. See [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#attribute-reflection) for more information.

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">

<dom-module id="reddit-list-service">
    <template>
        <iron-ajax auto url="https://www.reddit.com/new.json" handle-as="json" on-response="handleResponse"></iron-ajax>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "reddit-list-service",
        properties: {
            modhash: {
                type: String,
                value: ""
            },
            posts: {
                type: Array,
                value: function () {
                    return [];
                },
                reflectToAttribute: true, // note these two new attributes
                notify: true
            },
            after: {
                type: String,
                value: ""
            }
        },

        // Update object properties from the ajax call response
        handleResponse: function (resp) {
            this.modash = resp.detail.response.data.modhash;
            this.posts = resp.detail.response.data.children;
            this.after = resp.detail.response.data.after;
        }
    });
</script>
```

I have also tidied up the following things:

- Removed the immediately called function wrapper from the `<script>` tags as these are not needed.
- When referring to properties in your element you only need to use `this.PROPERTYNAME` rather than `this.properties.PROPERTYNAME`.
- Having looked at the JSON returned, it appears that the `author` property is on the another property called `data`.
- When you declare a value for a property in your element, you only need to have a function that returns a value if the property type is an `Object` or `Array`.

Comment: This is the same as a question I posed and answered myself [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30591409/using-polymer-ajax-response)

Comment: You really don't want `reflectToAttribute: true`, especially for Array or Object data. It spams your DOM with potentially massive JSON, and is not needed for binding.