# Polymer data binding -

Tags: javascript, polymer

Can someone tell me where i'm going wrong? I have an element **system-menu** that queries for data using **iron-ajax** then i'm supposed to bind that data to my template.

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-menu-behavior/iron-menubar-behavior.html">

<dom-module id="system-menu">
    <template>
    <iron-ajax
        auto
        url="{{url}}"
        params='{"ajax":"true"}'
        handle-as="json"
        on-response="dataLoaded"
        debounce-duration="300">
    </iron-ajax>
    <div class="content"><content></content></div>
</template>

</dom-module>

<script>
    (function() {
        Polymer({
            is: 'system-menu',
            behaviors: [
                Polymer.IronMenubarBehavior
            ],
            ready: function() {
            },
            properties: {
                data: {
                    type: Object,
                    reflectToAttribute: true,
                    notify: true
                }
            },
            attached: function () {
                this.data = [];
            },
            dataLoaded: function (data) {
                this.data = data.detail.response;
            }
        }); 
    })();
</script>
```

`

This is how I use the element,

```
<link rel="import" href="/themes/_components/custom_components/system-menu/system-menu.html">

    <system-menu class="list" url="www.some.site/widget/system-menu-widget/-menuRequest/">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items='{{data}}'>
            <li>{{item.label}}<li>
        </template>
    </system-menu>`
```

For some reason, the `{{data}}` isnt binding anything. It just shows `{{data}}` in the chrome inspect element console

Comment: I think the data must be exposed in some way before you can use it within the `dom-repeat` template. You could publish it as a read-only property for `system-menu` and then add something like `item-data="[[data]]"` to your used element.

Comment: @idleherb is correct. See the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30616297/4961460) for help on how to do this.

Comment: @Ben Thomas , i edited my question according to your suggestion but still nothing is showing up. Its still showing up as {{data}} after binding. and getting an error `Polymer::Attributes: couldn`t decode Array as JSON`

Comment: when you use `system-menu`, you need to set the `data` attribute on it. For instance: `<system-menu class="list" url="www.some.site/widget/system-menu-widget/-menuRequest/" data="{{data}}">`. Have you tried this?

Comment: @BenThomas thanks, its binding now. But still I cant use it. `<system-menu class="list" url="www.some.site/widget/system-menu-widget/-menuRequest/" data="{{data}}">` now shows up as `<system-menu class="list" url="www.some.site/widget/system-menu-widget/-menuRequest/" data="[{"category":"system","label":"home","url":"/home","parent_id":"0"},{"category":"system","label":"about","url":"/about","parent_id":"0"}]">` but how do i use it in `<template is="dom-repeat" items='{{data}}'>
  <li>{{item.label}}<li>
 </template>`   still getting ** couldn`t decode Array as JSON**

Comment: @BenThomas , do you mind posting that as an answer,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the `data` loaded from the `system-menu` outside of the `system-menu` element, you need to add it as an attribute:

```
<system-menu class="list" url="www.some.site/widget/system-menu-widget/-menuRequest/" data="{{data}}">
```